# Darboux property of the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}\sin\frac{1}{x}, &x<0 \\ \dfrac{x^2}{x+1}\cos x+\beta, &x\geq0, \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the function 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}\sin\frac{1}{x}, &x<0 \\ \dfrac{x^2}{x+1}\cos x+\beta, &x\geq0, \end{cases}$$

where $\beta\in \mathbb{R}$.

It is seen that the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ if $\beta=0$. So it has Darboux property.

How do I prove that it has Darboux's property, for $\beta\neq 0$?

Or that it doesn't own Darboux?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* A function with a [jump discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity) at $x_0$ cannot have the Darboux property in any neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta\neq 0$. Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}e^{-1/x^2}\sin\frac{1}{x}=0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
|f(x)|<\frac{|\beta|}{2},\qquad \textrm{for}\quad x\in (-\delta,0).
$$
Thus there exists no $x\in (-\delta,0)$ such that $f(x)=\frac{2}3 \beta$ even though $\frac{2}3 \beta$ lies between  $f(-\delta)$ and $f(0)$.